# How make htaccess for single-page app within a sub-path in URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to have a single-page app, but only within a sub URL like:

```
//The following would all be valid, but handled by the "index.html" 
//at http://www.test.com/webapp
http://www.test.com/webapp
http://www.test.com/webapp/settings
http://www.test.com/webapp/start
```

I want all the URLs to look exactly like above, but be handled by: `http://www.test.com/webapp/index.html`.

I also want the following URLs to ***not*** be handled by that page:

```
http://www.test.com
http://www.test.com/contact
http://www.test.com/about
```

How do I do this?

*REGULAR SINGLE_PAGE HTACCESS*

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [QA,L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: The same (with [QSA] not [QA]) but in the `webapp` directory

Comment: @Croises how do the first two rewrite rules change?

Comment: You change nothing. You just put this code in `.htaccess` in `webapp` directory

Comment: I had the same problem and I can confirm that using [QSA] did solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Just adding answer for reference.*

The commnet from  @Croises:

> "The same (with [QSA] not [QA]) but in the webapp directory"

Worked for me.

**The ".htaccess" must be on the subdieretory.**

Example working ".htaccess":

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [QSA,L]
</ifModule>
```

The only diference is "[QA,L]" to "[QSA,L]"

Comment: Could you explain the difference between this flags?

Comment: I don’t really know, one has an “A” :P, maybe @Croises can help

Comment: QSA maintains the query string. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 3):

The answer marked as good didn't work for me. Below my solution:

1) Create `.htaccess` in the folder where you place your app
2) Paste the code below
3) Change `folder_name` to your folder name.

```sh
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /folder_name/
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /folder_name/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have this very set up (replace folder_name with wordpress) and it is not working. When I set up react-router-dom to move about my SPA, I get 404 errors on any other path that is not `localhost:8888/wordpress`

Comment: @EricStermer, If errors come from React app, your React is misconfigured. If from Wordpress, you may need to configure mod_rewrite module.
 This works for me:
 1) On the server create folder for your React project (top level of Wordpress site next to wp-content folder...).
 2) Inside public folder in React project create this .htaccess file and adjust it properly
 3) Build React app and copy compiled files to the created folder on the server.
 4) If you use some kind of Wordpress firewall e.g. Wordfence you may need to add the app folder to Whitelisted URLs