# React Router URL not found if refresh page - Create React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I have an React app with different pages (ROUTER). I can go from a page to another, refresh the page and everything is working totally fine in local.

If I deploy the app `npm run built` and upload it to my host infinityfree.net all the time I want to refresh a page or use a direct link I get a 404 ERROR.

I tried catch all routes but it is not working

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="container">
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Main</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/SomethingElse">Something else</Link></li>
          </ul>
          <hr />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/SomethingElse" component={SomethingElse} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Any tips?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the catch all routes that you tried?

Comment: please specify if you are using a node app server to serve your app or just a web server to return your js files; if you are using node, please show us the server config

Comment: How are you hosting your app?

Comment: I run npm run built and I copy and paste the files into my File Manager area infinityfree.net

Answer (score 6):

Once you refresh a page in a different route your http server won't be able to get the file corresponding to that route since it doesn't exist

so you have to redirect all the routes to `index.html` which is the root of your app

so if you are using apache you can add `.htaccess` to the root of your project and this is its content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: had a similar problem as OP, thanks for your reply, it helped me as well, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the host to always leave the routing to react.
Search for `X routing config for react`, depending on what you use X can be Apache, Nginx, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me when I de0loyed my react app to netlify. You need to include a file called _redirects that contains the following line inside:

```
/* /index.html 200
```

Add this file to your build folder once you have run the deploy script and then upload it!

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't configured your hosting correctly.

When you access `mypage.example.com/` the server will give you the file `index.html`, which is the one that shows your app. Though, if you try to access `mypage.example.com/about`, the server will try to find the `about` folder and fail, giving you a 404 error.

What you should do is configure the server to always give you the `index.html` if the url isn't a real file.

Here is how you can do that for Apache: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45723487

Answer (score 0):

Htaccess file. There are a bunch of other things to consider too but this is my sites htaccess config:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
AddType x-httpd-php7 .php
```

Depends entirely on your server/deployment though!